# Appery.io iOS build error "Invalid pair of Provision Profile and Certificate"

Tags: ios, appery.io

I have generate provision certificate using developer key provide by Apple but getting following error

Invalid pair of Provision Profile and Certificate. Provisioning profile was not signed with a given developer certificate. Please open the project, then go to Project/App Settings/iOS binary IPA properties to check it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was returned to you in the error message: "Invalid pair of Provision Profile and Certificate"

It seems you didn't add this certificate into your provision profile or use another provision profile.

Just generate a new pair or them, and run the build again